# An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, exception

I'm doing a project in Nhibernate with MySql in asp.net. In that while executing the code I got the error like

> An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer

in the below line

```
ISessionFactory factory = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure).BuildSessionFactory();
```

So let me help to trouble shoot the error.

Here s my Configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <!-- an ISessionFactory instance -->
  <session-factory>
    <!-- properties -->
    <property name="connection.provider">
      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class"> 
      NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Server=localhost;Database=hrms;User ID=test;Password=test;
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_mysql">true</property>
    <!-- mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="WebApp1.Job.hbm.xml" assembly="WebApp1" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: You should post your configuration as well.

Comment: That error is quite generic and could be caused by numerous factors but one possible cause could be a missing or malformed `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Incomplete configuration perhaps? Try manual configuration initialization like the following:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
cfg.SetProperty("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect");
cfg.SetProperty("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver");
cfg.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", "Server=YourServer;Database=YourDatabase;User ID=YourId;Password=YourPass;CharSet=utf8");
cfg.SetProperty("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu");  
cfg.AddAssembly("Your.Assembly.Name");  
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

If everything works, move it to XML if you like.

Comment: Hi Jaya, sorry for this. Actually i'm new to this NHibernate. So let me tell u, hw can I cofigure mannualy using ur code.?

Comment: While using ur code, I got tat mapping exception was unhandled by user code error

Comment: Can you show me the mapping file and where did you put the mapping file? also in the code above, it is assumed that the mapping file is in the Your.Assembly.Name assembly.

Comment: I added my assemply file in tat place, but I got "Could not add assembly WebApp1.Job.hbm.xml" error..

Comment: you need to give the detailed error. or even better if you could show me the mapping file.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the inner exception that is being thrown and it's very likely you would know the cause. In my experience it can be as simple as the code is looking for the hibernate.cfg.xml file in bin/debug and could not find it.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Problem was that I used in Web.config:

```
<section name="nhibernate" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
<nhibernate xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    .
    .
    .
</nhibernate>
```

instead of:

```
<section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    .
    .
    .
</hibernate-configuration>
```