# NHibernate configuration error

Tags: nhibernate

I've just begun working as a developer and I'm running into the same issue over and over again. I keep getting this error:

> Exception (SessionFactory): An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer. /    em NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader hbConfigurationReader, Boolean fromAppSetting)
>      em NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(XmlReader textReader)
>      em NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(String fileName, Boolean ignoreSessionFactoryConfig)
>      em DataLayer.Repository.NHibernateHelper.get_SessionFactory() at 14/12/2016 16:52:52  0
>   PCService Error on: 14/12/2016 16:52:52  Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.   em DataLayer.Repository.ConfigRobotRepository.FindByName(String name)
>      em RSPC.PCService.ScheduleService() at line 0

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">
      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Server=localhost; Database=bd; Uid=ti; Pwd=************;
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My NHibernateHelper.cs:

```
public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_sessionFactory == null)
                    //CreateSessionFactory();
                    {
                        var configuration = new Configuration();
                        //configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, ConnectionString);
                        configuration.Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

                        configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(ConfigRobot).Assembly);

                        _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                    }

                    return _sessionFactory;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new     System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e, true);
                    var frame = trace.GetFrame(0);
                    var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
                    Log("Exception (SessionFactory): " + e.Message + " / " + e.StackTrace + " at {0} " + line, Path.GetTempPath() + "PCService" + ".txt");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this when you are debugging? Make sure you have your NHibernate config set to `Copy Always` so it ends up in the Debug and Release folders when you build/run.

Comment: you posted your password? :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas just edited, I didn't even notice it after working so many hours haha

Comment: @TyCobb It's configured to Copy Always with Embedded Resource selected for Build Action. Also, it's a Windows Service, so I haven't been able to debug it properly, I only get the error when I install and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are multiple reasons why this may happen:

- Are you sure `configuration.Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");` line is picking up config file correctly? Try specifying complete path. Make sure you are copying it to bin (release/debug) folder.
- Make sure details mentioned in config file are correct.
- Try configuring using code. Use `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();`. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407290/an-exception-occurred-during-configuration-of-persistence-layer) for details.
- Check `InnerException` of Exception being thrown. Keep running down the Exceptinn tree.
- Make sure your Entities and HBM files are correct and match with database structure. This is least likely cause because NHibernate throws different exception in that case mentioning exact name of class.